# Call in background php from nginx config

Tags: php, nginx, process, background, command

- I would like to know if it's possible from nginx.conf config file to
  call any php or os command with IF statement?

i.e.

- Sending Query String:

  http://server.com/index.php?cat=15
- And nginx config starting process in background

```
server {
    listen         201.2.18.131:80;
    server_name    server.com;

    if (!-f $request_query_cat?){
        execute? ('php myscript.php -arg1=$request_query_cat') ??
    }
}
```

Is there any solution to parse url and start scripts on nginx config side?

Answer (score 0):

It surely depends on what you are trying to achieve, but you probably can use [fastcgi_finish_request](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php) to achieve it. AFAIK it may allow you to kill connection to nginx and keep the php process running, similar to [register_shutdown_function](http://www.php.net/register_shutdown_function)

As for the nginx capabilities, no, ATM you can't launch "background commands". You have to use an upstream to launch anything or you can pick something from [3rd party modules](http://wiki.nginx.org/3rdPartyModules) to implement some kind of launcher. Like using a jobs scheduler/launcher like [torque](http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/products/open-source/torque/) that allows submitting jobs via network, then you only need to code the job submitting from nginx. Or create a poller on memcached or mongo that waits for nginx to insert a "flag" then executes a predefined job.

p.s. From my experience, launching uncontrolled background processes is the best way to get into a mess. Many of good intentions were burried in cronjobs launching every minute and stacking 1440 500MB php processes at the end of the day. Be careful.